# How do I strongly type a TypeScript web worker file with postMessage?

Tags: typescript, web-worker, typescript-typings

I have a web worker that I want to write with TypeScript.

The problem is [`Worker.postMessage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Worker/postMessage) - TypeScript assumes that every script will be loaded in the window context, and so expects [`Window.postMessage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/postMessage), which has a different syntax.

This means TypeScript throws an error when I try to use `postMessage`.

There are ways to work around this, for instance by redefining the function `declare function postMessage(message: any)`, but most of these are ugly kludges at best - the whole point of TS is checking types, declaring my own dummy ones defeats that.

By the same token - `window` (and everything in it's context) is not available in this context and should be picked up as an error by TS. For instance `alert('message')` should result in a TS warning, not a run time bug.

Is there any way to do it where the file can pick up the actual definition (from `webworker.es2016.d.ts`) and somehow tell TypeScript that this code will be running in the worker context instead of the window?

Answer (score 11):

If you check the [compiler options](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html) you will see that there is a webworker option for `--lib`. The problem is that you can't compile regular code and code for web worker at the same time. You can put your web worker code in a separate  folder with it's own `tsconfig.json` and copule it separately:

```
"compilerOptions" : {
    "target": "es2015",
    "lib": [
        "es2015"
        "webworker"
    ]
}
```

Or you can invoke the compiler explicitly for the webworker code:

```
tsc .\sample.ts -lib es2015,webworker
```

Comment: Unfortunately I'd like to be able to `import` some of the same libraries, so an effectively seperate TS project isn't a great solution. Is that the only way?

Comment: @Keith See this GitHub issue for a work-around, maybe you can apply it: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/20595

Answer (score 0):

Use [TypeScript references](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/project-references.html) to make your root `tsconfig.json` depend on subprojects, each with its own TypeScript config file.

You can have one TypeScript config file per environment in which your code runs, so you might have `tsconfig-browser.json`, `tsconfig-webworker.json`, and `tsconfig-node.json` files. You can use [configuration inheritance](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html) to reuse common options, and then you can override the options which aren't common, such as the libraries available in an environment's global scope.