# error TS2554: Expected 2-3 arguments, but got 1

Tags: javascript, typescript, web-worker

With given `tsconfig.json`,

```
{

    "compilerOptions": {

      "lib": ["es2015", "dom"]
    },
    "files": [
      "./project1/tstut.ts",
      "./project1/worker.ts"

    ]
  }
```

and [folder structure](https://github.com/shamhub/shamhub.github.io)

---

1)

For below code(`./project1/tstut.ts`),

```
if(window.Worker){
  console.log('Workers are available');
}
....
let worker: Worker = new Worker('worker.js');
worker.postMessage('do some work')
```

How to resolve below typescript error?

```
Property 'Worker' does not exist on type 'Window'
```

2)

For below worker code(`./project1/worker.ts`),

```
self.addEventListener('message', (e) => {
    // console.log(e)
    if(e.data === 'do some work'){
        console.log('Worker is about to start some work');
        let count: number =0;
        for(let i: number=0; i<1000; i++){
            count += i;
        }
        self.postMessage({message:count});
    }

})
```

JS allows syntax `self.postMessage({message: count})`

https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/582

Given [scenario](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48950463/3317808) does not fit in my case.

How to resolve below error for `postMessage()`? On running `tsc`

`Expecting 2-3 arguments, but got 1`

Comment: use `if ('Worker' in window)` instead

Comment: @artem for example, `window.alert` does not expect syntax `alert in window`. why `Worker in window`  syntax is expected for `Worker`?

Comment: but [Worker](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.dom.d.ts#L15196), for example, is declared as standalone (global) object in typescript DOM typings and does not expect syntax `window.Worker`

Comment: @artem How `Worker in window` different from `window.Worker`? Doesn't both syntax mean a property in `window` object.

Comment: it's the same in javascript. For TypeScript, it's determined by the way the types are declared in typings. For some reason `alert` was defined as property on `window` object in DOM typings, `Worker` was not.

Comment: @artem With this syntax, `interface Worker extends EventTarget, AbstractWorker{}`,  how `Worker in window` syntax indicates `Worker` as property of `window`?

Comment: it's not `Worker in window`, its' `'Worker' in window`, note the quotes around `'Worker'` - it's a string, and it's a check if a property with that name (given as an arbitraty string)  exists in `window` object at runtime.

Comment: @artem Does typescript compiler defer check of `'Worker'` property in `window` to run time? Because of syntax `'Worker' in window`

Comment: Yes, it's javascript syntax, it's not checked at compile time, only at run time

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Workers don't live on the window object.

```
if (typeof(Worker) !== "undefined") {
    // Yes! Web worker support!
    // Some code.....
} else {
    // Sorry! No Web Worker support..
}
```

To get around your webworker postMessage error, either use 'webworker' lib in tsconfig or the following

```
const ctx: Worker = self as any;
...
ctx.postMessage({message:count});
```

---

**Your code example**

**tstut.js**

```
if(typeof(Worker) !== 'undefined'){
    const worker = new Worker('worker.js');
    worker.postMessage('do some work');
    worker.addEventListener('message', function (e) {
        //console.log(e);
        console.log(e.data);
    });
}
```

**worker.js** (No need to check for worker support here)

```
const ctx: Worker = self as any;
ctx.addEventListener('message', (e) => {
    // console.log(e)
    if (e.data === 'do some work') {
        console.log('Worker is about to start some work');
        let count: number = 0;
        for (let i: number = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            count += i;
        }
        ctx.postMessage({ message: count });
    }
})
```

Comment: Code flow is going in `else` block and says `No webworker support`. Do i need to make some changes in `tsconfig.json`? `tsconfig.json` is in the query

Comment: It's because your doing the Worker check inside the worker. No need to do that.

Comment: In JS, we have `SharedWorker` object. Am trying to execute the same code using `let worker: SharedWorker = new SharedWorker('worker.js');` but I see the error `Cannot find name 'SharedWorker'`

Comment: Am able to use: `let worker: SharedWorker.SharedWorker = new SharedWorker('worker.js');` after installiing type definitions, but `worker.postMessage('do some work');` does not work

Comment: I think it is called 'webworker' instead of 'webworker**s**' lib in .tsconfig file according to the [documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html).

Comment: For anyone else wondering, when he says "use 'webworker' lib in tsconfig", he means put "webworker" in the "libs" list inside tsconfig.json.